# What’s the difference between don’t let jealousy get the best of you and let it take over you?

Tags: difference

I heard the phrase **don’t let jealousy get the best of you** from a song, and I’m wondering if I could change it to **don’t let jealousy take over you** without changing the meaning of the phrase?

Comment: Nope. While the meanings are close, they're not identical. "Get the best of" suggests a temporary situation, and also suggests that the person was tricked by jealousy. The other phrase, "take over you" suggests not only a permanent situation, but a complete domination of the individual. Also, what is up with rewriting song lyrics anyways? What's wrong with the original?

Comment: @FeliniusRex There’s nothing wrong with the original. I just wanted to pinpoint the exact meaning of ‘get the best of’ by comparing it what I would have said to convey the same meaning!

Comment: OK, cool. :) No worries.